# Scrapy merging to 1 list

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've build my 1st Scrapy project but can't figure out the last hurdle.
With my script below I get one long list in csv. First all the Product Prices and than all the Product Names.

What I would like to achieve is that for every Product the price is next to in.
For example:

```
Product Name, Product Price
Product Name, Product Price
```

My scrapy project:

Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class PrijsvergelijkingItem(Item):
    Product_ref = Field()
    Product_price = Field()
```

My Spider called nvdb.py:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import scrapy.selector
from Prijsvergelijking.items import PrijsvergelijkingItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):

name = "nvdb"
allowed_domains = ["vandenborre.be"]
start_urls = ["http://www.vandenborre.be/tv-lcd-led/lcd-led-tv-80-cm-alle-producten"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//ul[@id='prodlist_ul']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = PrijsvergelijkingItem()
        item["Product_ref"] = titles.xpath("//div[@class='prod_naam']//text()[2]").extract()
        item["Product_price"] = titles.xpath("//div[@class='prijs']//text()[2]").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this can help you, but you can use OrderedDict from collections for your need.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import scrapy.selector
from collections import OrderedDict
from Prijsvergelijking.items import PrijsvergelijkingItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):

name = "nvdb"
allowed_domains = ["vandenborre.be"]
start_urls = ["http://www.vandenborre.be/tv-lcd-led/lcd-led-tv-80-cm-alle-producten"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//ul[@id='prodlist_ul']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = OrderedDict(PrijsvergelijkingItem())
        item["Product_ref"] = titles.xpath("//div[@class='prod_naam']//text()[2]").extract()
        item["Product_price"] = titles.xpath("//div[@class='prijs']//text()[2]").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Also you might have to change the way you iterate dict,

```
for od in items:
    for key,value in od.items():
        print key,value
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch your XPath expressions to work in the context of every "product". In order to do this, you need to prepend a dot to the expressions:

```
def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath("//ul[@id='prodlist_ul']/li")
    for product in products:
        item = PrijsvergelijkingItem()
        item["Product_ref"] = product.xpath(".//div[@class='prod_naam']//text()[2]").extract_first()
        item["Product_price"] = product.xpath(".//div[@class='prijs']//text()[2]").extract_first()
        yield item
```

I've also improved the code a little bit:

- I assume you meant to iterate over list items `ul`->`li` and not just `ul` - fixed the expression
- used the `response.xpath()` shortcut method
- used `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`
- improved the variable naming
- used `yield` instead of collecting items in a list and then returning

Comment: Thank you alecxe. One more little issue, now I only have 1 result, but I want all of them.

Comment: @Wouter I suspect that's because you need to locate the `li` elements inside the `ul` - updated the answer. Did I guess right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you geussed it right, thank you. I have 2 more questions which I hope you can help me with. The € sign is coming out in as "â‚¬Â " how can I ignore this. And 2nd question. The pricing comes out as for example: 199,00. Of course if I put his in excel I get a colomn only with zero's. How can I solve this?